# Add elements of an array together in ARM assembly language (raspberry pi)

Tags: arrays, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I have this array working. The program loops correctly, but this is as far as I can get.

Im trying to understand how I can save the first element, 13, to another register, then when the program
 loops, have the next element in the array added to that register and once all elements have been added, to display the sum of them all when I branch to exit.

The issue is when I try this, I keep getting illegal use of register errors or segmentation faults... I have no idea on the syntax, or how to use the registers to print. Our professor hasn't given us a lot of documentation to look through and I've been searching online for awhile with no luck.

Thanks

```
@
@ int ary[] = {13, 44, 7, 29};
@ int main()
@ {  for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
@      printf("ary[%d] = %d\n", index, ary[index]);
@ }
@ ---------------------------------------
@       Data Section
@ ---------------------------------------

        .data
        .balign 4       
output: .asciz  "ary[%d] = %d\n"
ary:    .int    13
        .int    44
        .int    7
        .int    29

@ ---------------------------------------
@       Code Section
@ ---------------------------------------

        .text
        .global main
        .extern printf
        .extern scanf

main:   push    {ip, lr}        @ push return address + dummy register
                                @ for alignment
        mov     r5, #0          @ index = 0
        ldr     r4, =ary        @ get the address of ary
for:    cmp     r5, #4          @ index < 4?
        bge     exit            @ no

print:  mov     r1, r5          @ print index
        ldr     r2, [r4, r5, LSL #2] @ get ary[index]
        ldr     r0, =output
        bl      printf          @ print index and ary[index]
        add     r5, r5, #1
        b       for

exit:   pop     {ip, pc}        @ pop return address into pc
```

Comment: Well, you can't do much if you "have no idea on the syntax". Finding some sort of an ARM assembly syntax reference is a much easier task than posting a question here which you've just done. Besides, everything you're asking for is already shown in your code: *mov*, *add* and the way *printf* is used for output. Post your attempt (by editing the question body) and we'll be able to help with any specific errors.

Comment: This [Wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) is a very good start to get a basic understanding of the ARM arch. The only "tricky" (for a novice) part in your task is the use of an external function *printf* (part of C standard library), you need to remember that a function is allowed to destroy (the content of) certain registers, so you either have preserve them on the stack if you use them for your 'sum' or better just avoid using. This is detailed in [AAPCS](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf) but for your needs: r0-r3, r12(ip).

Comment: ... and r14 (lr).

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what exact errors you get.  This is important so we can understand your thinking process and helps us give you the best possible advice.